# Can we write "use strict" at the top of our JS file and It would validate all functions and statements?

Tags: javascript

Do we have to write `use strict` in all of the functions we have in our JS files or would writing it at the top of the code be enough to validate everything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add it once at the top of the file.

See this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

> Strict mode applies to entire scripts or to individual functions.
>
> To invoke strict mode for an entire script, put the exact statement "use strict"; (or 'use strict';) before any other statements.

```js
// Whole-script strict mode syntax
'use strict';
var v = "Hi! I'm a strict mode script!";
```

Answer (score 0):

`'use strict'` is lexically inherited, just like variable scope. A function will run in strict mode if it contains `use strict` *or* if an ancestor block has `use strict`. You only need to write it once.

```
(() => {
  'use strict';
  // put all your code here
})();
```

For front-end, if you have lots of code for which putting it all in a single file would seem too unwieldy, consider using a bundler like Webpack, which can let you write scripts in separate files and then combines them into a single strict bundle.

For Node, you *do* have to write `'use strict'` at the top of every file, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For Node.js you will have to wirte `use strict`;  at top of every file

for more reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30634600/12904989